# C++/CImg inconsistent results

Tags: c++, cimg

Below, I have a simple program which uses the CImg library (http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) which iterates through the pixels of an image and outputs either a 0 or 1 for each pixel based on its grayscale value (light or dark). What's quite strange is that I'm getting different results every time I run the program (with the same input).

If I do

```
image.display()
```

it works as expected, so it seems CImg is reading the image properly. However, if I attempt to print AvgVal in the inner for loop, I get different values every time. I'm using OSX 10.7.3 and gcc 4.2.1, if that makes any difference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "CImg-1.4.9/CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cout << "Usage: acepp inputfile outputfile" << std::endl;
    }

    else {
        std::ofstream outputFile(argv[2]);
        if (!outputFile.is_open()) throw std::runtime_error("error: cannot open file for writing");

        CImg<unsigned char> image(argv[1]);
        int RVal, GVal, BVal, AvgVal, outBit;
        for (int iHeight = 0; iHeight < image.height(); iHeight++) {
            for (int iWidth = 0; iWidth < image.width(); iWidth++) {
                RVal = image(iWidth,iHeight,0,0);
                GVal = image(iWidth,iHeight,0,1);
                BVal = image(iWidth,iHeight,0,2);
                AvgVal = (RVal + GVal + BVal) / 3;
                outBit = 1;
                if (AvgVal > 127) outBit = 0; // low is dark, high is light
                outputFile << outBit;
            }
            outputFile << std::endl;
        }
        outputFile.close();
        std::cout << "Done writing to: " << argv[2] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've been reading SO for a while, but I just registered, so I can't post the example images I'm using. I'll just describe them - they were 10px x 10px png images containing black and white patterns, authored using Photoshop CS5.

Comment: How are you printing ArgVal when you say "if I attempt to print AvgVal in the inner for loop". Sample outputs you get from that including expected output would be good in lieu of any actual images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input .png file is a grayscale one (one channel only, as it is permitted by the .png format), then probably, your Gval and Bval are assigned with random values taken from invalid memory access. As a consequence, your AvgVal may be wrong, and resulting image may be different each time you run the program.

Comment: Thanks, that was what was causing the problem. The png I was using was a single channel image.

In case anyone else is having this problem - it was easy to fix. I used the member function spectrum() which returns the number of channels in an image. Then I iterated through all the channels adding the value to an accumulator, and finally divided the accumulator by image.spectrum()